# SQL Inner Join and Sub Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery, inner-join

I have written the following statement and it returns the data I am looking for, showing multiple rows for each customer charge that was added to the OrderNo. I am looking to incorporate a sub query that would return the total cost (Sum) of FK_OrderNo.

For instance, Order Number 4915 has 4 customer charges, so after it displays the 4 entries, I want to have a row that shows the total charges. See picture link below for the results that I get currently.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rlrH4.png

Here is my code so far:

```
![Use AirTrak
SELECT PK_OrderNo
      ,Housebill
      ,OrgAirport
      ,DestAirport
      ,CallIn
      ,CallInName
      ,Description
      ,APARType
      ,Total
      ,TotalMiles
      ,OrderDate
      ,PODDateTime
      ,ShipmentDateTime
      ,InvoiceDateTime

From dbo.tbl_ShipmentHeader as SH
     Inner Join dbo.tbl_ShipmentAPAR as SC
      On SH.PK_OrderNo = SC.FK_OrderNo
        where SH.BillNo = 2003 and
        SC.APARCode= 'C'
```

Comment: Can you supply your expected output? And is this sql-server or mysql?

Comment: You're going to need to use UNION with a second  query that gets your totals, assuming this is MySQL.

Comment: The expected output would be the sum of the PK_OrderNumber. For instance, 4915 has 4 charges totaling 1148.35. I would like a row to show up under the 4 charges that shows a grand total.

Comment: Also, I updated the post to be just SQL Server and not my-sql. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to get the SUM on a second query if you want a new row with it.
With UNION ALL you can union the 2 sets. Without the ALL keyword it will do a DISTINCT on your sets.

```
DECLARE
    @Bill INT = 2003;

SELECT PK_OrderNo
      ,Housebill
      ,OrgAirport
      ,DestAirport
      ,CallIn
      ,CallInName
      ,Description
      ,APARType
      ,Total
      ,TotalMiles
      ,OrderDate
      ,PODDateTime
      ,ShipmentDateTime
      ,InvoiceDateTime

From dbo.tbl_ShipmentHeader as SH
     Inner Join dbo.tbl_ShipmentAPAR as SC
      On SH.PK_OrderNo = SC.FK_OrderNo
        where SH.BillNo = @Bill  and
        SC.APARCode= 'C'
UNION ALL
SELECT PK_OrderNo
      ,NULL
      ,NULL
      ,NULL
      ,NULL
      ,NULL
      ,NULL
      ,NULL
      ,SUM(Total)Total
      ,NULL
      ,NULL
      ,NULL
      ,NULL
      ,NULL

From dbo.tbl_ShipmentHeader as SH
     Inner Join dbo.tbl_ShipmentAPAR as SC
      On SH.PK_OrderNo = SC.FK_OrderNo
        where SH.BillNo = @Bill and
        SC.APARCode= 'C'
GROUP BY
    PK_OrderNo
```

Comment: Thank you for the post MXIX. When I run that query, it just reports back the same information, except for its sorted by the Order Number now.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with group by rollup! this is an example, not your data but i think easy to understand and customizable to your needs:

```
DECLARE @orders TABLE
(
    orderID INT,
    item VARCHAR(30),
    quantity INT,
    price float
)

INSERT INTO @orders
VALUES
(1,'Daiwa Aqualite Powerfloat',1,74.90),
(1,'Berkleys Firewire',220,0.12),
(1,'Cat Boilies Blood Flavour',1,6.49),
(1,'Black Cat Dead Bait Rig',2,5.00),
(2,'Shimano Alivio DX',1,69.90),
(2,'MAD Carpline',250,0.08),
(2,'Alfa Boilies 1KG Tutti Frutti',1,6.49),
(2,'Exner Strong Waggler 8g',1,5.25)

SELECT  orderID,
        CASE WHEN orderID IS NULL
            THEN '--   GRAND TOTAL   --'
            ELSE COALESCE(item,'- TOTAL FOR ORDER ' + CAST(orderID AS VARCHAR(5)) + '-')
        END AS item,
        SUM(quantity * price) as linetotal
FROM     @orders
GROUP BY ROLLUP(orderID, item);
```

Comment: CeOnSql, I like where you are going with this, however, SSMS doesn't like the CASE statement. It says that its expecting '(' or select.

Instead of doing it like you have, how would I do something like this:
For each PKSEQ that has the same FK_OrderNo, sum the totals field and output it to a field called Shipment Total?

Comment: Before you build a case statement i would execute the query (in above example) with `select orderID, item, SUM(quantity*price) as linetotal...`  Then you can see what the output is and it will be easier for you to build a good case statement.  See this link, it helped me to understand how `ROLLUP` works: http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/using-the-rollup-cube-and-grouping-sets-operators.html

Answer (score 0):

Try the following query. The only thing that the total amount will be repeated as results are not unique.

```
SELECT
  PK_OrderNo,
  Housebill,
  OrgAirport,
  DestAirport,
  CallIn,
  CallInName,
  Description,
  APARType,
  Total,
  TotalMiles,
  OrderDate,
  PODDateTime,
  ShipmentDateTime,
  InvoiceDateTime,
  sd.total_charge
FROM (SELECT
       PK_OrderNo,
       SUM(charge) total_charge
     FROM /*your charge table*/
     GROUP BY PK_OrderNo) sd,
     dbo.tbl_ShipmentHeader AS SH
     INNER JOIN dbo.tbl_ShipmentAPAR AS SC
       ON SH.PK_OrderNo = SC.FK_OrderNo
WHERE SH.BillNo = 2003
AND SC.APARCode = 'C'
AND charge_table.PK_OrderNo = SH.PK_OrderNo
```